# Why isn't GHCi letting me annotate my types with kinds?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I found out about Kinds while reading a History of Haskell paper and tried to run some of the examples at [the Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Kind).

When I do, I get the error

```
Prelude> Int :: *                                                                                                 [3/1792]

<interactive>:1:8: error:                                                                                                 
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘*’                                                                           

<interactive>:1:8: error:
    Illegal operator ‘*’ in type ‘*’
      Use TypeOperators to allow operators in types
```

I don't think 'importing' TypeOperators will help because I think GHCi believes * is the multiplication operator, when I want it to denote a Kind.

[This wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Kinds) seems to suggest that Kinds may not have been added to my version of GHC yet. Could this be the case?

I am using GHCi version 8.0.2 (from Ubuntu 18.04 package manager).

Comment: That is not a type definition. A type definition starts with `data`, or `newtype`, etc.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how type definitions are relevant here. Int is a type, and I would like to annotate it with a Kind. I took the line `Int :: *` straight from the Haskell wiki.

Comment: @overseas `Int` is not a value or declaration, so you cannot just write `Int :: *` in GHCi. You need to tell GHCi that you are writing a type, for instance by defining one via `data` or `newtype`, or using the `:k` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check kinds in GHCi, you might want to use the following

```
> :set -XKindSignatures
> :k (Int :: *)
(Int :: *) :: *
```

or omit the `:: *` part and let `:k` figure it out for you.

Typing `Int :: *` directly would make GHCi interpret `Int` as a value expression, and look for a non existent value constructor `Int`. It would also interpret `*` as a type, instead of a kind, which causes an error.

Comment: thanks! this is close to what I was looking for. Sorry to be obtuse, but why is 'Int' interpreted as a value expression? I thought that Int was a type. Is it because (foo :: bar) is always interpreted by GHCi as (valueexpr :: sometype) by default?

Comment: @overseas Yes, it's for that reason. We could define `data T = Int deriving Show` and then ask GHCi `Int :: T`. Haskell was originally defined with two distinct namespaces for value constructors and types. Kind syntax as in `T :: *` was only added later, and in GHCi you need `:k`. In Haskell source files it can only appear in precise contexts e.g. type definitions `data A (f :: * -> *) = A (f Bool)` where it is clear that the `::` is at kind level.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to have the name of a data type's value constructor be the name of another data type (referring to `data T = Int`). This seems dangerous, since if I type `data R = R; data L = R; x = R` and query for the type of x, I get `x :: L` as result (so R has been shadowed by L?).

Comment: @overseas That is actually forbidden in the same module since `R` is used twice at the value level. In GHCi some "magic" is used to allow for that, pretending that each definition is, roughly, in a separate module. That's why in GHCi you can do `x = True` and then `x = False` and then `x = "hello"` which looks as a redefinition.